# Laravel components with dynamic attributes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am using Laravel and creating components with their associated PHP classes. I will take my use case as an example:

**Views/P.php**

```
class P {

    public function render() {
        return view('views.p');
    }
}
```

**resources/views/p.blade.php**

```
<p class="pb-4"></p>
```

Above I am using Tailwind utility classes to add padding bottom.

Now, I can use this component and similar ones within my application. For example:

**some.blade.php**

```
<x-h1>Title</x-h1>
<x-p>Hello world</x-p>
```

Notice that I have also included an `<x-h1>`. This could also have a similar bottom padding.

I want to be able to remove the padding with an attribute like this:

**some.blade.php**

```
<x-h1 no-margin>Title</x-h1>
<x-p no-margin>Hello world</x-p>
```

But now I need to define the logic to do that in both PHP classes. I have the logic contained either in a parent class or trait, but the issue I have is that for each component I will need to define the attributes in the constructor, like this:

**Views/P.php**

```
class P {

    use noMarginModifier;

    public $noMargin;

    public function __constructor($noMargin = false) {
        $this->noMargin = $noMargin;
        // do something from noMarginModifier trait
    }

    public function render() {
        return view('views.p');
    }
}
```

**Views/H1.php**

```
class H1 {

    use noMarginModifier;

    public $noMargin;

    public function __constructor($noMargin = false) {
        $this->noMargin = $noMargin;
        // do something from noMarginModifier trait
    }

    public function render() {
        return view('views.h1');
    }
}
```

Which for this example is ok, however, I am going to soon extend the amount of attributes, there might be `no-margin`, `higlight` etc. etc.

The only way I can think of doing this is by containing all attributes in one property like this:

**Views/H1.php**

```
class H1 {

    use modifier;

    public $modifiers;

    public function __constructor($modifiers = []) {
        $this->modifiers = $modifiers;
        // do something with modifiers
    }

    public function render() {
        return view('views.h1');
    }
}
```

The only trouble with this solution is that I will have to use the components like so:

```
<x-h1 :modifiers="['no-margin' => true]"></h1>
```

Which just makes writing a heading with no margin a little cumbersome.

I would prefer to be able to automatically get the attributes from the component definition.

Answer (score 2):

One solution I have, but it feels a little flakey due to the caveats mentioned is to access the attributes and slots within the component class as mentioned in the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#using-attributes-slots-within-component-class).

This results in having a class like:

**Views/H1.php**

```
class H1 {

    use modifier;

    public function render()
        {
            return function (array $data) {            
                // no-margin exists here
                $data['attributes']['no-margin'];
                // do something with modifiers
                return 'components.h1';
            };
        }
    }
```

However, the caveat I am seeing in the template is:

**resources/vies/h1.blade.php**

```
{{ $attributes->merge(['no-margin' => 'anotherValue']) }}
```

When I merge an attribute like above. Then the change is not reflected in the template.